# VSCode debug move breakpoint back to previous

Tags: vscode-debugger

In `Visual Studio` usually I take the current break point and move it back to the previous line but in `vscode` I don't know how to do it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible commands that may help you - they don't work that well for me but you may have better luck.

I believe you are looking for the `debug.jumpToCursor` command which doesn't have a default keybinding.  Put your cursor on the previous line and trigger the command.

It doesn't show up in the command palette for some reason so you will have to set your own keybinding for it to work.  In keybindings.jon:

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+'",
    "command": "debug.jumpToCursor"
  },
```

Your language server may not support this functionality though yet, it is fairly new.  See also [github issues: jump to cursor](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25653).

There is also a `Run to cursor` command.  Move your cursor where you want and right-click, "run to Cursor" is in the context menu.  See the link above for the differences between these two commands:

> "Move to line" can be used to set the PC (Program Counter) to any
>   location without executing the code between the current location and
>   the destination. So you can even go backward with this. "Run To
>   Cursor" can only go forward and executes everything in between.

Answer (score 0):

I also would love a `Run to previous cursor` debug option. It can take a long of time to restart your app, just so you can get to a previous line of code. I added a feature request. https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/discussions/6262